# MongoDB show duplicate key is null?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB version 3.6

I got the duplicate key message when I executed this. What's the actual problem?

```
mongos> db.setup.findAndModify({
... query : {"_id" : ObjectId("5b3c7abbea95705803084cad")},
... update : {$set : { "test" : "xxxx" }},
... upsert : true
... })
2018-07-06T10:13:22.749+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.setup index: name dup key: { : null }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1530872002, 603),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1530872002, 602)
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.findAndModify@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:724:1
@(shell):1:1
mongos>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected case if you have defined a unique index which is non-sparse: documents [missing a value for the field with the unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field) will have an indexed value of `null`. This means that only a single document in the collection can be missing the unique field.

The duplicate key message includes the index name and key violation:

> "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.setup index: name dup key: { : null }",

In your example, the collection `setup` in database `testdb` has a unique index on the `name` field. The attempted upsert failed because the `name` field was missing and there was already a document in this collection with a missing or `null` value for `name`.

If you want to use a unique index without requiring the field to be present you have a few  options:

- Drop and recreate the unique index with the `sparse` property:

  ```
  db.setup.createIndex(
      {name: 1},
      {unique:true, sparse:true}
  )
  ```
- Drop and recreate the unique index using a [partial filter expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraints) (which allows further criteria if needed):

  ```
  db.setup.createIndex(
     { name: 1},
     { unique:true, partialFilterExpression: {name: {$exists:true }}}
  )
  ```

Comment: Thanks, @Stennie, it's my bad to not see "name" field in error message.

Comment: Hi. This is not working for me. It still complains about duplicates in the unique field. Can "duplicate documents" contains the field {...,"name":null,...} or they just should not contain that field?

Comment: @Miguel I suggest posting a new question with relevant details for your environment (MongoDB server version, driver version, error message, ...).

Comment: @Stennie, I just posted the question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230768/mongodb-does-not-allow-to-create-unique-partial-index-in-field-that-contains-nul). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Delete the collection from the DB and then hit he API , it will work. There is no mistake in code.

Comment: it would be great if you'd register your account and add some details around your answer.  Maybe a pointer to the documentation that shows how to delete the collection or something.

Answer (score 1):

I found other indexes on that collection have been set "unique" to be "true" (exclude _id) then it shows error.