# MongoDB does not allow to create unique partial index in field that contains null

Tags: index, mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I'm using MongoDB 3.6.9 (with Ubuntu) to save a set of documents that contain one field named `rss_id` and for some documents, this field has the value `null`. I want to create a unique index in that field and tried [this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211650/173315). From the documentation it seems a good solution but for some reason, I can't make it work in my MongoDB.

When I excute the folowing command (I'm using the shell of Robo 3T):

```
db.getCollection('noticias').createIndex(
   { rss_id: 1},
   { unique:true, partialFilterExpression: {rss_id: {$exists:true }}}
)
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: newsWall.noticias index: rss_id_1 dup key: { : null }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey" }
```

Comment: Multiple `NULL`s are treated as duplicate values for a unique index.

Answer (score 3):

So my theory is to create a partial index with a unique constraint with a filter expression such that the partial index will add an entry only if the type is not the type 'null'.  I specify all types except null to make this happen.   For a list of types see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type

```
db.noticias.createIndex(
  { rss_id: 1},
  { 
    unique: true, 
    partialFilterExpression: {
      rss_id: {
        $type: [
          "double",
          "string",
          "object",
          "array",
          "binData",
          "undefined",
          "objectId",
          "bool",
          "date",
          "regex",
          "dbPointer",
          "javascript",
          "symbol",
          "javascriptWithScope",
          "int",
          "timestamp",
          "long",
          "decimal",
          "minKey",
          "maxKey"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below query to create the unique partial index. The reason why your query work is, there may many fields with the value like `{rss_id: null}`

```
db.getCollection('noticias').createIndex(
   { rss_id: 1},
   { unique:true, partialFilterExpression: {rss_id: {$ne:null}}}
)
```

Or you can use [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-and-unique-properties) option along with unique index as shown below

```
db.getCollection('noticias').createIndex( { rss_id: 1}, { sparse: true, unique: true })
```

Comment: receiving error `"errmsg" : "unsupported expression in partial index: $not\n    rss_id $eq null\n",`

Comment: Sparse indexes look for existence of a field, not the value (if null or otherwise).

Comment: received "errmsg" : "unsupported expression in partial index: $not\n    rss_id $eq null\n"